# Outlook does not show hyperlink when filename contain space in it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to paste hyerlink in body of mail in outlook by flex application using navigateToUrl method with mailTo protocol.

but outlook breaks hyperlink after first space in hyperlink.

I tried with < ,> before am after link but it doesnot help out me.

Is there any other way to paste link in body mail containing space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to url-encode the whole message:

```
 var url:String = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + escape(subject) + "&body=" + escape(body);
 navigateToUrl(new URLRequest(url));
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing spaces with `%20`. If that doesn't work, try using `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, It tried with for %20,outlook also encode it into space and for &nbsp; it removes part of url after space.but replied to this question by pkyeck works so I would like to suggest you to check this reply.